# Mailer Limited to 10 Groups

Tags: civimail

On a Drupal 7.56 / CiviCRM 4.7.27 site, since the last update, when making a mailer we can only add 10 groups and then it doesn't allow us to add more.

Previously it worked for more than 10 groups.

I see no errors in front end nor back end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known (fixed) bug, [CRM-21468](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21468).  You can apply [the patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11349/files) manually if you feel comfortable; otherwise, it will be fixed in CiviCRM 4.7.29.